# Nested scroll doesn't works in RadAutoCompleteTextView(Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

In the nativescript application, if we are using the `RadAutoCompleteTextView` inside the `ScrollView` and the length of the form goes beyond your screen size, the scroll event of the RadAutoCompleteTextView doesn't work.

Check the [sample app](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=MtzdJZ) to reproduce the issue. In the sample app, add the tokens in autocomplete field(in the last row of the form) to fill it up beyond 4 lines. After that, try to scroll the tokens, you won't be able to scroll up to see previously added tokens.

Comment: I think your sample code is incomplete, the HTML template uses forms / mode flag etc., those which are not defined in TS. Please share a Playground sample where issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj, I apologize for that. I updated the question and changed the link to Playground sample.

Comment: Try using NestedScrollView plugin instead of ScrollView.